# JavaScript, Making POST and GET requests simultaneously using Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, promise, get

**Background**: I have a function that needs a small debugging which is related to API requests(POST,GET) and promises. For the past few days, I have been trying to figure how asynchronous functions work and it turns out it's impossible (or so I heard) to directly return a value from such functions to synchronous functions.

My initial idea was to make a POST request function that returns an access token which I could plug to the authorization header of my GET function (which works perfectly so long as a token is provided). From my discovery, however, I can't do this on two separate methods because the POST request returns undefined outside the function. So my idea now is to include the GET request within the POST so that the access token can be passed directly without any method call. I tried to do this using Promises which I'm not very familiar with but manage to make some sense. My expectation was that I can call the `httpGetData()` function which would first get token, then pass it to a `.then()` portion which is supposed to return actual data or `[object Promise]` instead of undefined.

**Question**: The issue is that when I call the `httpGetData()` function it returns `undefined` but my `console.log(result[0])` shows clearly that the GET request has fetched the data I want. I was wondering if there is a tweak that would allow my code to **return** this data (`console.log` is useless for me other than to see what's happening on background of api request). I saw some SO questions like these answered by returning the values in the `.then()` but my attempts all return undefined.

I've attached screenshots of the outputs. Keep in mind this is an Alexa skill Lambda code so the return appears after `.speak()` and the `console.log` shows below.

```
function httpGetData() {

  var promise1 = new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
    var options = {
      method: "POST", // POST request intended to get access token
      host: 'hostinfo',
      path: "pathinfo",                                                        
      headers: {
        "content-type": "stuff here",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
     }
  };

  var request = http.request(options, function (response) {
    var returnData = [];

    response.on("data", function (chunk) {
      returnData += chunk;
    });

    response.on("end", function () {
      var data = JSON.parse(returnData);
      var accessToken = data.access_token; // the access token value of the POST api request like "039509544932n3249fc21232nc32423nci"
      resolve(accessToken);
    });

    response.on('error', (error) => {
      reject(error);
    });
  });

  request.write("------stuff: form-data; name=\"client_secret\"\r\n\r\stuff here\r\n------stuff: form-data; name=\"client_id\"\r\n\r\stuff here\r\n------stuff: form-data; name=\"grant_type\"\r\n\r\nclient_credentials\r\n------stuff");
  request.end();

  }));

  promise1.then(function(value) {
      return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
        var options = {
          method: "GET", //this is a GET request so it's intended to get usable data using access token
          host: 'hostinfo',
          path: "pathinfo",                
          headers: {
            "content-type": "stuff here",
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + value, // value is the access token that was resolved earlier ("039509544932n3249fc21232nc32423nci") so I'm trying to concatonate this to the authorization header
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
         }
    };

      var request = http.request(options, function (response) {
        var returnData = [];

        response.on("data", function (chunk) {
          returnData += chunk;
        });

        response.on("end", function () {
          console.log(value); //this is the line that prints access token in screenshot
          resolve(JSON.parse(returnData));
        });

        response.on('error', (error) => {
          reject(error);
        });
      });

      request.write("------stuff: form-data; name=\"client_secret\"\r\n\r\stuff here\r\n------stuff: form-data; name=\"client_id\"\r\n\r\stuff here\r\n------stuff: form-data; name=\"grant_type\"\r\n\r\nclient_credentials\r\n------stuff");
      request.end();

        }))
  }).then((result) => {
            console.log('hello');
            return result; //I'm not sure here but wanted to return the result 
            }).then((result) => {
                  console.log(result[0]); // just a check which shows that result[0] actually executes and can be printed as shown in screenshot
                  return result[0]; //other desperate attempt


});


}// httpGetData() function ends here
```

[return image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdF2v.png)

[Console log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvH7s.png)

Comment: If I'm understanding your code correctly, the problem you're having here is that while you're calling `return result[0]`, it's returning a value for the function you've declared in the `.then`, rather than `httpGetData`, which will have actually finished executing long before the `.then` is reached. The only thing I can think is to have `httpGetData` accept a callback.

Comment: `which is supposed to return actual data or [object Promise] instead of undefined` - Quick question here as well, do you just want the function to return the pending promise so you can await it elsewhere? if so you can just add `return promise1` to the end of your function.

Comment: But what use does the .then() have if it's not waiting on the promised data from the httpGetData() function? Also, are promises and callbacks separate things or should they be used together? I have tried previously to use callbacks like httpGetData(callback)  but I kept getting "type error: callback is not a function" which was a hassle as I'm new to this.

Comment: Yes I wanted to return the pending promise as there is a different async/await function waiting to get the value.

Comment: callbacks were the primitive solution to async/await. If you want to actually wait for a promise to resolve, you need to make the function asynchronous and use the `await` keyword before your promise. `.then` is allowing you to say, 'hey promise, when you're done, execute this function', however, it doesn't await it like the keyword does, so your `httpGetData` function won't wait on the promise to resolve.

Comment: `Yes I wanted to return the pending promise as there is a different async/await function waiting to get the value`. All you need to do here then is add `return promise1` to the end of your `httpGetData` function, and it'll return the pending promise which you can await else where to get the result once it's been resolved.

Comment: @OllysCoding I see, I tried returning promise 1 at the very end (which does return [Object Promise], however the promise is still undefined if I want to access it. I brought up the [object promise] idea because my separate GET functions would return this (when I manually plug a new token) and if I wanted to access them using other functions they'd show the output which I've posted under console picture...

Comment: just as a reference my other functions are supposed to use the httpGetData function using this code:
async handle(handlerInput) { 
const response = await httpGetData() 
console.log(response); 
var string = dataStorage((response[0].items)); //dataStorage is another function which parses through the response

Comment: "*I can't do this on two separate methods*" - yes you can, and you should. Those methods would indeed not return result values synchronous, but they would return a promise for the access token and a promise for the resource data.

Comment: @Bergi it would be awesome to implement two separate methods (I'm just struggling to grasp their separate asynchronous implementation). However, I would also like to know if there's a way to make this request done on a single function.

Comment: @AbenezerAyana That single function would then just look like `return getAccessToken().then(token => getResource(token));`. Of course you could also inline the two functions, but it's easier to understand and implement separately.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you so much, it works! I agree its much understandable now that I have separated POST and GET methods which can be called by a single function. I will be posting the working code below for people that experienced the same issue! Thank you very much again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally solved the problem thanks to @Bergi. Although this answer can be shortened, I want to post it so that it can serve as an option. What Bergi suggested was that instead of having both the POST and GET requests done in one function, we can separate them and use another function to do execute them simultaneously. In the code below, **httpToken()** performs the POST request and returns an access token. The **httpResource(accessToken)** function performs a GET request where it will take an accessToken parameter. The other function, **finalData()** will help us make the POST and GET requests simultaneously hence returning an **[object Promise]** instead of undefined, which we can access. Our last step will be to have an async/await function (**retrieveInfo()**), which will use finalData() to get the response from our requests. Enjoy!

```
function httpToken() {
  return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
    var options = {
      method: "POST",
      host: 'hostinfo',
      path: "pathinfo",                                                        
      headers: {
        "content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
     }
  };

  var request = http.request(options, function (response) {
    var returnData = [];

    response.on("data", function (chunk) {
      returnData += chunk;
    });

    response.on("end", function () {
      var data = JSON.parse(returnData);
      var accessToken = data.access_token;
      resolve(accessToken); //resolving access token (can be changed to resolve(data) to include timestamp etc)
    });

    response.on('error', (error) => {
      reject(error);
    });
  });

  request.write("------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"client_secret\"\r\n\r\n"client secret here"\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"client_id\"\r\n\r\n"client id here"\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"grant_type\"\r\n\r\n"grant type here"\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--");
  request.end();

  }));
}


function httpResource(accessToken){
      return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
        var options = {
          method: "GET",
          host: 'hostinfo',
          path: "pathinfo",                                                       
          headers: {
            "content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken,
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
         }
    };

      var request = http.request(options, function (response) {
        var returnData = [];

        response.on("data", function (chunk) {
          returnData += chunk;
        });

        response.on("end", function () {
          resolve(JSON.parse(returnData));
        });

        response.on('error', (error) => {
          reject(error);
        });
      });

      request.write("------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"client_secret\"\r\n\r\n"client secret here"\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"client_id\"\r\n\r\n"client id here"\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"grant_type\"\r\n\r\n"grant type here"\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--");
      request.end();


    }));
}

function finalData()
{
  return httpToken().then(token => httpResource(token));
}

async function retrieveInfo()
{
    response = await finalData(); //response will have the data returned from our GET request using finalData()

    //do stuff with response...
}
```